# Getting a file from a dynamic download URL with PHP in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I'm trying to automate downloading a file (in this case it's a PDF invoice) on wordpress order completed hook.

I have first tried to download it using wp_remote_get which seemed simple, but without success (no file downloads):

```
function download_pdf_invoice__on_order_completed( $order_id, $order ) {

wp_remote_get( "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'download_pdf_invoice__on_order_completed', 20, 2 );
```

So far I have managed to make it work and download any file with cURL as long as the extension is in the URL, but I can't get it to work with my dynamic download URL, which is this test/demo URL:
https://www.moloni.com/downloads/index.php?action=getDownload&h=b75b2d99c08c56480da0c5dff4900b4a&d=189279574&e=teste@moloni.com&i=1&t=n

```
function  action_woocommerce_admin_order_get_invoice_pdf($url){
//The resource that we want to download.
$fileUrl = 'https://www.moloni.com/downloads/index.php?action=getDownload&h=b75b2d99c08c56480da0c5dff4900b4a&d=189279574&e=teste@moloni.com&i=1&t=n';

//The path & filename to save to.
$saveTo = '/myserver/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-functionality-master/logo.jpg';

//Open file handler.
$fp = fopen($saveTo, 'w+');

//If $fp is FALSE, something went wrong.
if($fp === false){
    throw new Exception('Could not open: ' . $saveTo);
}

//Create a cURL handle.
$ch = curl_init($fileUrl);

//Pass our file handle to cURL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

//Timeout if the file doesn't download after 20 seconds.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

//Execute the request.
curl_exec($ch);

//Get the HTTP status code.
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//Close the cURL handler.
curl_close($ch);


}
   

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_get_invoice_pdf', 20, 2 );
```

However if I replace the $fileUrl with this sample PDF http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf then it will work

I have considered implementing some sort of error / log to be able to see what errors could be caused by the code however I have not figured it out how to do this under these circumstances of hooking the download to the woocommerce order completed action

Comment: Why not simply use `file_get_contents($fileUrl)` instead of cUrl? Just don't forget to place somewhere that file content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file_get_contents` to download file from URL.

```php
$fileUrl = 'https://www.moloni.com';
$saveTo = ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-functionality-master/logo.jpg'

file_put_contents(
    $saveTo,
    file_get_contents($fileUrl)
);
```

---

Comment: I had tried file_get_contents before but it did not work, however your code is working great with any link even my dynamic download one is downloading successfully! Thanks Justinas